# How to overlay a rectangular image on its blurred square version

Tags: css

I would like to convert a rectangular image to a square image, but without losing information about the original image. My idea was to create a square image, then I would blur it and I would overlay the rectangular image on it, so something similar:

[image: example]

All this should use HTML+CSS only. To do this, I use Photoshop right now but a way to replicate this behavior using CSS would be amazing because it would save me a lot of time.
I don't have any idea how to do that because the main problem is that the rectangular image should have the same height (or width, if width > height) as the square blurred image and it should be responsive (so no fixed size, it depends on the size of the original image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Image Box</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Image Box</h1>
        <div class="image-box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* style.css */

.image-box {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image-box::before,
.image-box::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}

.image-box::before {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px) brightness(0.8);
}

.image-box::after {
    background-image: inherit;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: inherit;
    background-repeat: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).